# Filtering dataframe based on two column string match count

Tags: pandas

I want to filter data rows based on string from data['Age'] and count atleast two occurence of that pattern "o;", "i;", "twenty;", "a;" in data['Name'].

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['To;om', 'ni;cki;', 'krish', 'jack'],'Age':['o', 'i', 'twenty', 'a']})

data
      Name     Age
0    To;om       o
1  ni;cki;       i
2    krish  twenty
3     jack       a
```

Output should look like this:

```
      Name     Age  count
0  ni;cki;       i    2
```

Comment: But i have to add the pattern ";" to original data['Age'].  To;om also have two occurance of 'o'. but single occcurence of 'o;' But it should be filtered out.

Comment: Why is `To;om` filtered out?

Comment: Because the pattern is "o;". Not "o".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
In [427]: data[data.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].count(f"{x['Age']};") >= 2, 1)]
Out[427]: 
      Name Age
1  ni;cki;   i
```

Comment: Sorry Mayank. There is one caveat in that. That is adding one more regular expression pattern ";" to the original string from data['Age'].

Comment: @AlagurajVeluchamy I've updated my answer to handle the caveat. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension to find the counts and then filtering with it:

```
df["count"] = [name.count(age) for name, age in zip(df.Name, df.Age)]
out = df[df["count"] >= 2].copy()
```

to get

```
>>> out

      Name Age  count
1  ni;cki;   i      2
```

The `copy` at the end is to avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning in possible future manipulations.

Comment: Yeah I know, but in this case both answers are applicable to OP's question.